# Sharing objects between view and application with Pyramid

Tags: python, pyramid, deform, colander

I'm trying to create a web interface for a data analysis pipeline using Pyramid. I'm using deform and colander to make the forms. I've been adapting this example:

http://pyramid-tutorials.readthedocs.org/en/latest/humans/security/step02/

Most of the work gets done when a form gets submitted, but there are a couple of generic steps that only need to run once. Can I load some things into memory when the server starts up so that they are accessible from within a view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define some module level variables in the main file of your application (or may be somewhere else) and then use them by importing them as per your requirement.

I use this method to create settings like database connection string for SQLAlchemy from environment variables.

By default, a module will be parsed only once in Python, so you module level code will run only once.

## Update 1

Let's assume directory structure of a pyramid project looks like this:

```
.
├── __init__.py
├── models
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── meta
│   │   ├── base.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── orm.py
│   │   ├── schema.py
│   │   ├── types.py
│   ├── users.py
├── security.py
├── settings
│   ├── database.py
│   ├── email.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── redis.py
│   ├── security.py
├── static
│   ├── css
│   │   └── main.css
│   └── js
│       ├── app.js
│       ├── app-services.js
│       ├── controllers
│       │   └── excel_preview.js
├── templates
│   ├── auth
│   │   └── login.html
│   ├── base.html
│   ├── home.html
├── views
│   ├── auth.py
│   ├── home.py
│   ├── __init__.py
```

Let's say we've following code in `settings/redis.py`:

```
import os
import redis


def get_redis_client():
    # Read settings from environment variables
    redis_db_name = os.environ.get('REDIS_NAME')
    redis_host = os.environ.get('REDIS_HOST')
    redis_port = os.environ['REDIS_PORT']

    # create a redis connection
    redis_client = redis.StrictRedis(
        host=redis_host,
        port=redis_port,
        db=redis_db_name,
    )

    # return newly created redis connection
    return redis_client


redis_client = get_redis_client()

SOME_SETTING_STORED_IN_REDIS = redis_client.get('some_setting_stored_in_redis')
```

You can use this `SOME_SETTING_STORED_IN_REDIS` variable from anywhere. If name of your app is `example_app` then in `example_app/views/home.py` you can use it like this:

```
from pyramid.view import view_config

from example_app.settings.redis import SOME_SETTING_STORED_IN_REDIS


def includeme(config):
    config.add_route('home', '/')


@view_config(
    route_name='home',
    renderer='home.html',
    permission='authenticated'
)
def home_view(request):

    return {
        "some_setting": SOME_SETTING_STORED_IN_REDIS,
    }
```

I think you're trying to achieve something similar.

Comment: Thanks, I am new to Pyramid, so I may be missing something obvious. If I set up a global in the application like this:

`global foo
foo = "this is a global"`

I still get an error when I try to print it from the view:

`NameError: global name 'foo' is not defined`

One thing I notice is that the application and the view don't import each other explicitly. I think the server identifies the view block to run using a decorator.

Comment: I have added some sample code for you. I've used module level variables instead of globals.

Comment: Thanks! This solution works for me, although it took me a little while to understand why. I think I get flow of control in Python a little better now.

Answer (score 0):

If by "things which only need to run once" you mean something like a database connection, some configuration data etc. - in other words something which never changes during the lifecycle of the process then defining them as globals and re-using across the application is fine. Example:

```
APP_TITLE = 'Data Analysis Pipeline using Pyramid'

@view_config(...)
def home_view(request):
    return "Welcome to %s" % APP_TITLE
```

If you're thinking about storing some *global state* and re-using it across the views then it would not be a good idea. Example (bad, do not do this):

```
subscription_step = 1

@view_config(...)
def next_subscription_step(request):
    global subscription_step
    subscription_step += 1 
    return HTTPFound('/subscription/step_%s' % subscription_step)
```

The above code may appear to work for you locally, but things will start fall apart as soon as there's more than one user accessing the app, or if the webserver spawns another worker process, or if the webserver restarts, or a million of other reasons.

Comment: Good advice. I don't need to update the data across views, I just to load some data into memory so that every view can see it.